# Como hacer diferentes dibujos en Canvas con android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

Llevo unos días estudiando el tema y no acabo de enterarme

Estoy tratando de hacer diferentes figuras geométricas en canvas según el botón que se pulse, pero no doy con la forma de llamar al método onDraw y pasarle figura y tamaño que deseo

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class PaginaDibujo extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnCerrar;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    View myView;
    ImageButton btnColores;
    Button Ci;
    Button Cu;
    Canvas canvas;
    String circulo = "cirulo";
    String medida = "pequeño";

    ImageView image;
    private int corx, cory;
    private int corx2, cory2;
    private Lienzo fondo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_dibujo);

        findViewById();

        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        fondo = new Lienzo(this);
        fondo.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener) this);
        layout1.addView(fondo);

        btnColores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                metodoAbrirFragmenColores();
            }
        });

        btnCerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Ci.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fondo.onDraw(canvas, circulo, medida);
            }
        });

        Cu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void findViewById() {
        btnCerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCerrarMover);

        btnColores = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnColores);
        Ci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCirculo);
       Cu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCuadrado);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                myView.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                myView.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                myView.invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    class Lienzo extends View {
        public Lienzo(PaginaDibujo paginaDibujo) {
            super(paginaDibujo);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, String figura, String medida) {
            Paint mPaint = new Paint();

            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

            if (figura.equals("circulo")){
                if (medida.equals("pequeño")){
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, mPaint);
                }
                else if (medida.equals("mediano")){
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 20, mPaint);
                }
                else if (medida.equals("grande")){
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 30, mPaint);
                }
            }
            else if (figura.equals("trianguloSubir")){

            }
            else if (figura.equals("trianguloBajar")){

            }
            else if (figura.equals("cuadrado")){

            }
            else if (figura.equals("estrella")){

            }
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }

        public Lienzo(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que desearía, sería una vez pulsado el botón Ci, me dibujara un círculo llamando al método OnDraw pasándole el String figura y la medida

No se como se podría hacer, tampoco si voy en la dirección correcta

Alguien me podría asesorar ?

Tambien desearía, luego poder editar cada figura dibujada y poder moverla de lugar

gracias

Comment: `onDraw` es una función que creaste tú. Debes reemplazar la función del padre con la del hijo mediante `@Override`.  Y a lo mejor te interese más usar un `SurfaceView`

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @Mateo, pero no logro entender lo que me dices. La verdad es que el código lo busqué por internet y no consigo saber como funciona.

Comment: Que te olvidaste agregar `@Override` a la función `onDraw`.  Y la otra sugerencia es usar un [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/android/view/SurfaceView) que es mejor específicamente para dibujar.